# how to scrape selected values from yahoo finance key statistics page using R, following API removal

Tags: r, rvest, yahoo-finance

Now that yahoo finance appears to have removed their api, I need some code to scrape selected values from the key statistics page.

e.g. for url [https://uk.finance.yahoo.com/quote/IPX.L/key-statistics?p=IPX.L]

I wanted the values for "Trailing P/E" (14.68 as of today), "Book value per share (mrq)" (0.93 as of today) & the latest price & time of that (543.00 At close : 06:01PM BST as of now).

Have tried with rvest but can't seem to get there.
Always seem to get empty results.
Might be something to do with external pointers ?

If there's also a general solution, that would download all the key statistics into a dataframe with the relevant labels displayed on the url for each, that would be great too.

If you can help, that would be fab & would likely help many others too given the API removal.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`rvest::html_table()` can extract all the tables from the page. For latest price
and time you can use css ids and attribute values to filter down to the
elements of interest. See below:

```r
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)
library(xml2)

# Get HTML
url <-
  "https://uk.finance.yahoo.com/quote/IPX.L/key-statistics?p=IPX.L"
yh_html <- read_html(url)

# Latest price and time
yh_html |>
  html_elements("#quote-header-info fin-streamer[data-field=regularMarketPrice]") |>
  html_text()
#> [1] "543.00"

yh_html |>
  html_elements("#quote-market-notice") |>
  html_text()
#> [1] "At close:  06:01PM BST"

# All tables
fin_tables <-
  yh_html |>
  html_table() |> 
  bind_rows()

fin_tables
#> # A tibble: 60 × 2
#>    X1                        X2     
#>    <chr>                     <chr>  
#>  1 Market cap (intra-day)    727.96M
#>  2 Enterprise value          658.81M
#>  3 Trailing P/E              14.68  
#>  4 Forward P/E               13.55  
#>  5 PEG ratio (5-yr expected) N/A    
#>  6 Price/sales (ttm)         4.16   
#>  7 Price/book (mrq)          6.08   
#>  8 Enterprise value/revenue  3.76   
#>  9 Enterprise value/EBITDA   8.51   
#> 10 Beta (5Y monthly)         1.40   
#> # ℹ 50 more rows
```

Comment: If it's easy to add consolidating the list of 10 tibbles into 1 dataframe with field names equal to Revenue (ttm) et.c. with the corresponding values shown in the second column, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: `bind_rows()` can be used for that. I updated my answer.